# Cocoapods error while running ios app which leads error in pod install

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to create both ios and android app and It works fine for android but for ios while running `flutter run` it will take lot of time installing pod using `pod install` and at last it will give an error as shown below.

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
         Cloning into
         '/var/folders/f6/g4njsx3x5tx5dswcbsh29tdh0000gn/T/d20210605-16785-1rc0t
         ko'...
         fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git/': Failed to
         connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

I tried these posts but no luck 
[error running pod install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135078/how-to-solve-error-running-pod-install-in-flutter-on-mac/63504980) 
[error running pod install pods-runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142900/flutter-error-running-pod-install-pods-runner-target-has-transitive-dependen)

---

**pubsec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+17
  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.10
  image_cropper: ^1.4.0
  firebase_core: ^0.3.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.13+1
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  web_scraper:
```

If any extra information needed, Let me know in comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many research I found a solution,

**Step 1: I removed all cocoapods and it's directory using**

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall EACH_OF_THEM  // here EACH_OF_THEM means all the listed cocoapods
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
```

**Step 2: Installed HomeBrew**

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

**Step 3: Install cocoapods using HomeBrew**

```
brew install cocoapods
```

**Step 4: remove Podfile.lock if present**

```
cd ios
rm Podfile.lock
```

**Step 5: Now install pod**

```
pod install --repo-update
```

> It will take lot of time to download and install all the dependencies.

Now, If I run flutter project using `flutter run`. It succeed

```
...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
...
```

refered link : [dev.to](http://dev.to/idawnwon/error-running-pod-install-after-add-cloudfirestore-to-flutter-5lj)

Answer (score 0):

My Xcode is version is 15.0.1 , M1 apple chip and simulator is iPhone 15 plus. I had the same issue after installing Firebase, the [this](https://dev.to/idawnwon/error-running-pod-install-after-add-cloudfirestore-to-flutter-5lj) link helped me to fix the issue. Internet speed was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of different things going on so I'm going to give you a general list and hopefully, something helps!

- If you're using a VPN, disconnect from it
- Restart router and computer
- Try on a different network Try from a different workspace Try: git
  clone --depth=1
  https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template.git
- If none of those steps work you might want to consider downloading
  the repo as a zip and working with it locally.

Hope this helps!

Courtesy of valentinojosh from GitHub:
[Here is the link to the original answer](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/48568#discussioncomment-5108608)